# Скомпиленный через PyInstaller exe не коннектится к SQLite3 при запуске от имени администратора

Tags: python, база-данных, windows, sqlite, pyinstaller

Ситуация следующая. Как становится понятно из заголовка, после компиляции `PyInstaller`'ом `exe`-файла, при выполнении запуска от имени администратора, в консоль вылетает следующая ошибка:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "main.py", line 26, in 
>   sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
>   Failed to execute script main

База данных лежит на сервере. Сетевой диск `Z:\`. Вот строка, делающая обращение к базе:

`db = sqlite3.connect(path_to_db)`

Дело в том, что при обычном запуске, все работает. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Вероятно, сетевой диск подключён для не-elevated пользователя, а из-под администратора туда доступа нет. Попробуйте запустить какой-нибудь файловый менеджер вроде Far из под администратора, и посмотрите, будет ли доступ к файлам на сетевом диске.

Comment: Спасибо, @diversenok. Действительно, через `Far` от администратора не зашло на сетевой диск.

Answer (score 0):

Как было выяснено — проблема не в питоне, а в том, что у администратора нет доступа к подключённому сетевому диску.

Решение:
[Доступ на сетевой диск от имени администратора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/674496/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0)