# Доступ на сетевой диск от имени администратора

Tags: windows, сеть, smb

Есть пользователь, принадлежащий группе администраторов и имеющий включённый Контроль Учётных Записей (UAC). Для этого пользователя подключается сетевой диск.

- Для процессов, запущенных без администраторских привилегий доступ на этот диск есть.
- Для процессов, запущенных тем же пользователем, но от имени администратора доступа на этот диск нет.

Как исправить такое поведение?

Comment: На этом вопросе круглая дата загорелась `150,000 вопросов` :)

Comment: @Visman, вау, круто. Это ведь одна из привилегий с 10k репутации — подобная статистика, верно? А то не могу понять, где это написано)

Comment: Просто ваш вопрос был последним, когда на главной было `150,000 вопросов`. Все просто :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эти процессы запускаются с разными маркерами доступа. При подключении сетевого диска/папки они ассоциируются с конкретным маркером, и потому не доступны от имени другого.

**Решения**:

**1)** Можно запустить подключение сетевой папки/диска ещё раз, уже от имени администратора, и настроить доступ для него.

- Графический интерфейс: `rundll32 SHELL32.dll,SHHelpShortcuts_RunDLL Connect`
- Консольный: `net use Z: \\remote-pc\share /u:domain-name\username password`

Естественно, запускать эти команды надо от имени администратора.

**2)** Windows позволяет добиться ожидаемого поведения за счёт изменения настроек. Несмотря на явную принадлежность этой настройки к локальным/групповым политикам, я не нашёл её упоминания там (буду признателен, если вы её найдёте), а потому это делается через реестр.

Надо создать ключ `EnableLinkedConnections` типа DWORD в ветке `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System` со значением `1`.

После перезагрузки (или просто перезапуска сервиса `LanmanWorkstation`) все сетевые папки будут одновременно доступны и до, и после запроса UAC.

*Стоит отметить, что в этом случае все сетевые диски, созданные от имени администратора, также окажутся доступны и без администраторских привилегий.*