# Ошибка проверки доступности сетевой папки PowerShell

Tags: powershell, скрипт, доступ, диск

Есть скрипт написанный на `PowerShell`:

```
$path1 = "Y:\"
if ((Test-Path $path1)) {Write-host "Папка существует"}
else {Write-host "Папка не существует"}
```

---

Подключен сетевой диск `Y:\`, и нужно проверить, есть ли доступ в данный момент.

Запуская скрипт через `cmd` без `UAC`, все отрабатывает нормально **(True)**, а когда `cmd` с `UAC`, пишет обратное **(False)**.

А когда переменная `$path1 = "C:\Users\"`, даже с правами администратора все работает нормльно.

---

**Теперь, все работает когда запускаешь эти скрипты от имени админа, но не работает когда запускаю эти скрипты из под планировщика заданий, как теперь быть...**

Comment: Сетевой диск (при активном UAC) подключается в пользовательском режиме. В административном режиме - сетевого диска нет. Логично, что скрипт, выполняемый в административном режиме, не находит сетевой каталог. Проще говоря, административный и пользовательский режим разделяют в памяти исполняемые приложения, соответственно, на две сеанса(session).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот что нашел в интернете:

### [Доступ на сетевой диск от имени администратора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/674496/288376),

> Эти процессы запускаются с разными маркерами доступа. При подключении
>   сетевого диска/папки они ассоциируются с конкретным маркером, и потому
>   не доступны от имени другого.
>
> **Решения**:
>
> **1)** Можно запустить подключение сетевой папки/диска ещё раз, уже от имени администратора, и настроить доступ для него.
>
> - Графический интерфейс: `rundll32 SHELL32.dll,SHHelpShortcuts_RunDLL Connect`
> - Консольный: `net use Z: \\remote-pc\share /u:domain-name\username password`
>
> Естественно, запускать эти команды надо от имени администратора.

---

Мне помогла эта команда выполняемая от имени Администратора на `Windows Server 2008 r2`:

```
net use Y: \\remote-pc\folder1 /u:remote-pc\Username password
```