# Отключение запроса прав администратора при удалении и копировании файлов

Tags: python, windows, sqlite, windows-10, pyqt5

Всем доброго времени суток. Возникла проблема. Написал коротенькую программку - апдейтер на `python`, `PyQt5`, `SQLite3`. Программка маленькая, поэтому привожу код полностью:

```
import sys
import sqlite3
import os, shutil
import subprocess

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

from updater import *


def startup():
    # Запускаем приложение
    # cmd = 'decimator.exe'
    # PIPE = subprocess.PIPE
    # p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
    # p.wait()
    os.startfile(r'd:\\Programs\\decimator\\decimator.exe')
    sys.exit()


class Updater(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.ui.btn_ok.clicked.connect(self.download)

    def download(self):
        self.completed = 0
        try:
            # Удаляем текущий экзешник
            os.remove(path_to_current_file)
        except:
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Ошибка', 'Проблема с удалением текущего файла', QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Ok, QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Ok)

        try:
            # Копируем с сервера новый экзешник
            shutil.copy(path_to_new_file, path_to_current_file)
            file_version = open('./version.txt', 'w')
            file_version.write(latest_ver)
            file_version.close()
        except:
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Ошибка', 'Проблема с записью нового файла',QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Ok, QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Ok)
        while self.completed < 100:
            self.completed += 0.0001
            self.ui.progressBar.setValue(self.completed)
        self.ui.label.setText('Обновление завершено')
        # После удаления скрываем окно и запускаем скачанную программу
        self.hide()
        startup()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.offset = event.pos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        try:
            x = event.globalX()
            y = event.globalY()
            x_w = self.offset.x()
            y_w = self.offset.y()
            self.move(x - x_w, y - y_w)
        except AttributeError:
            pass


if __name__ == '__main__':

    path_to_db = open('./path.txt', 'r').read() # Путь к базе, "Z:\\BASE\\d2.db"
    path_to_new_file = open('./path_new_file.txt', 'r').read() # Путь к новому файлу, который надо скачать, "Z:\\BASE\\decimator.exe
    path_to_current_file = './decimator.exe' # Экзешник приложения, который надо удалить
    db = sqlite3.connect(path_to_db)
    c = db.cursor()

    current_ver = open('./version.txt', 'r').read() # Текущая версия программы
    latest_ver = c.execute("SELECT ver FROM versions WHERE id=1").fetchall()[0][0] # Последняя версия, вбивается ручками в базу

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle(QtWidgets.QStyleFactory.create('Fusion'))

    if current_ver != latest_ver:
    # Если версии не совпадают, то запускается окошко с фейковым прогресбаром и кнопкой обновить
        start = Updater()
        start.show()
    else:
        # Если версии совпадают, то просто запускается программа
        startup()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Проблема в том, что при компиляции в `.exe` при помощи `PyInstaller`, на экзешник вешается триждыпроклятый щиток выполнения от имени администратора... И все бы ничего, но база данных и файл, который необходимо скачать, лежат на сервере, а к серверу доступ есть только под обычным юзером, вот [ссыль](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/673921/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-pyinstaller-exe-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BA-sqlite3-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8) на описание проблемы. Как можно заставить приложение запускаться без прав админа? Помогите пожалуйста. `UAC` отключал, запрос на запуск от админа не выдает, но на сервер не пускает. И на экзешнике таки остается висеть щиток ...

Comment: Если  создать ключ `EnableLinkedConnections` типа `DWORD` в ветке `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System` со значением `1`, то все работает, но использовать программку будет n-ное количество сотрудников, поэтому не хотелось бы подобных танцев с бубном.

Comment: `cmd /c "set __compat_layer=RunAsInvoker&экзешник.exe"`

Comment: Если полный скрипт состоит из `import getpass; print("Hello " + getpass.getuser())`, то по прежнему проблема с PyInstaller у вас остаётся? Какое имя пользователя вы хотели бы чтобы этот скрипт напечатал?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Благодаря товарищу, оставившему комментарий, я смог решить проблему несколькими способами.

1: Создаем `.bat` файл со следующим содержимым и кидаем в папку с экзешником, который необходимо запускать. Все должно работать, можно приблудой `Bat To Exe Converter` конвертнуть все это дело в `.exe`:

```
set __COMPAT_LAYER=RUNASINVOKER
start "" myprogram.exe
```

2: Создаем `.reg` файл с кодом:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00 

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\forcerunasinvoker]
@="Run as invoker" 

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\forcerunasinvoker\command]
@="cmd /C \"set __COMPAT_LAYER=RUNASINVOKER && start \"\" \"%1\"\""
```

Запускаем, ... voilà . В контекстном меню появляется пункт `Run as invoker`, запускающий приложение принудительно без предоставления прав администратора.
Надеюсь когда-нибудь, кому-нибудь это поможет.

P.S. Немножко не понял про `import getpass`, этот модуль не использую, почитал, как понял, он реализует ввод паролей в генерируемые формы в webприложениях, так?
Если да, то скоро мне понадобится, так как начал изучать `Django`, что весьма не просто, учитывая полное отсутствие опыта в `web-разработке`.
Всем спасибо.